# how can i get value through json array

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

I'm not sure how to access string values within a JSONArray. My json looks like this:

{
"size":2,
"limit":25,
"isLastPage":true,
"values":[
{
"id":980,
"text":"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAh/gQGOHM+pZpA+ZnjNrqKqBadfxEbfvPlB0O\r\nJPFidREuqRFDqrLYcOTalk+jA02RqJ33",
"label":""
},
{
"id":996,
"text":"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAh/gQGOHM+pZpA+ZnjNrqKqBadfxEbfvPlB0O\r\nJPFidREuqRFDqrLYcOTalk+jA02RqJ33",
"label":""
}
],
"start":0
}

My code look like this

JSONObject output1 = (output != null && !output.equals("")) ? new JSONObject(output) : null
String id30 = (output1 != null && output1.get("values.text") != null) ? output1.get("values.text") : null

I try to get text

Answer (score 0):

Like so for example

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 

 class Example {
 static void main(String[] args) {
  def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
  def object = jsonSlurper.parseText('{ "size":2, "limit":25, "isLastPage":true, "values":[ { "id":980, "text":"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAh/gQGOHM+pZpA+ZnjNrqKqBadfxEbfvPlB0O\r\nJPFidREuqRFDqrLYcOTalk+jA02RqJ33", "label":"" }, { "id":996, "text":"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAh/gQGOHM+pZpA+ZnjNrqKqBadfxEbfvPlB0O\r\nJPFidREuqRFDqrLYcOTalk+jA02RqJ33", "label":"" } ], "start":0 }') 
    

  println(object.values.text[0])
  println(object.values.text[1])
 } 
}
```

You can also loop through the array like so:

```
      for (int i=0; i< object.values.size(); i++)
        println(object.values.text[i])
```